# Quotes escape in Where clause in LINQ to Entites

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, escaping, sql-injection

I wonder how to escape quotes in LINQ to Entities.

This is my environment : Entity Framework 5 with Silverlight 5 and WCF RIA Services, MySQL 5.6 and MySQLConnector 6.5.6.

I've got the following query:

```
DomainContext.Load<Product>(DomainContext.GetProductQuery()
                                         .Where<Product>(p => p.name.Contains(parameter))
                                         .Take<Product>(30));
```

If the **parameter variable** contains a quote `'` it raises a MySQL syntax error exception. 
Whatever the method (StartWith, Contains) it always raises an exception.

This does the same using **FilterDescriptor** with a **DomainDataSource**.

**Important note** : It does not raise any exception with characters like `%` or double quote `"`. Also it does not raise any exception with a simple quote if the operator is **equal strict** like the following.

```
DomainDataSource.FilterDescriptors.Add(new FilterDescriptor("productName", FilterOperator.IsEqualTo, SelectedProductName));
```

or

```
DomainContext.Load<Product>(DomainContext.GetProductQuery()
                                         .Where<Product>(p == parameter)
                                         .Take<Product>(30));
```

**I don't have any difficulties to insert data.**

Any help will be much appreciated. 
Thank you.

**Update**: I forgot to mention some things.

This is my method on service side.

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProduct()
{
    return this.ObjectContext.product;
}
```

How am I supposed to secure this against SQL injections ? Do I have to write dozens lines of code to manage filters ?

**EDIT** : Issue is solved in the last version of the MySQL provider for EF.

Comment: Are you **sure** you need **so much** text in **bold**? Please **consider** edit to decrease amount of **highlighted** text.

Comment: I use bold text to focus on key words. So I think yes I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround for this issue.

First, I would like to thank **tomlev** from www.developpez.net for his solution as **chamamo** for his help too.

This is the direct link to the discussion in French
http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1349604/services-web/wcf-ria-services-injection-sql/

This is the source code of a wrapper to fix this issue.

```
    class MySqlQueryableWrapper<T> : IQueryable<T>
{
    private readonly IQueryable<T> _queryable;
    private readonly IQueryProvider _provider;

    public MySqlQueryableWrapper(IQueryable<T> queryable)
    {
        _queryable = queryable;
        _provider = new MySqlQueryProviderWrapper(queryable.Provider);
    }

    public Type ElementType
    {
        get { return _queryable.ElementType; }
    }

    public Expression Expression
    {
        get { return _queryable.Expression; }
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        get { return _provider; }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _queryable.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

class MySqlQueryProviderWrapper : IQueryProvider
{
    private readonly MySqlExpressionFixer _visitor = new MySqlExpressionFixer();
    private readonly IQueryProvider _provider;

    public MySqlQueryProviderWrapper(IQueryProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        return _provider.CreateQuery(_visitor.Visit(expression));
    }

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        return _provider.CreateQuery<TElement>(_visitor.Visit(expression));
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        return _provider.Execute(_visitor.Visit(expression));
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        return _provider.Execute<TResult>(_visitor.Visit(expression));
    }

}

class MySqlExpressionFixer : ExpressionVisitor
{    
    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        if ((node.Method.Name == "Contains" || node.Method.Name == "StartsWith") &&
            node.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(string) &&
            node.Arguments.Count == 1)
        {
            var c = node.Arguments[0] as ConstantExpression;
            if (c != null)
            {
                string s = c.Value as string;
                if (s != null)
                {
                    s = s.Replace("'", "''");
                    node = Expression.Call(node.Object, node.Method, Expression.Constant(s));
                }
            }
        }

        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }
}
```

Here is an example.

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProduct()
{
    return new MySqlQueryableWrapper<Product>(this.ObjectContext.product);
}
```

Comment: I reported this bug. This issue is solved in the last version of the MySQL provider.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick solution for your exact problem:

```
string cleanParameter = parameter.Replace("'", "\'")
```

OR

Take a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/483763/Equivalent-function-of-mysql_real_escape_string-in) for a more general solution that describes the C# equivalent of mysql_real_escape_string.

```
string cleanParameter = MySQLEscape(parameter)
```

MySQLEscape as described in the mentioned article:

```
private static string MySQLEscape(string str)
{
    return Regex.Replace(str, @"[\x00'""\b\n\r\t\cZ\\%_]",
        delegate(Match match)
        {
            string v = match.Value;
            switch (v)
            {
                case "\x00":            // ASCII NUL (0x00) character
                    return "\\0";   
                case "\b":              // BACKSPACE character
                    return "\\b";
                case "\n":              // NEWLINE (linefeed) character
                    return "\\n";
                case "\r":              // CARRIAGE RETURN character
                    return "\\r";
                case "\t":              // TAB
                    return "\\t";
                case "\u001A":          // Ctrl-Z
                    return "\\Z";
                default:
                    return "\\" + v;
            }
        });
}
```

Side note: your code sounds like it may be prone to **SQL injection attacks**.  (I can't tell without more context).  This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev) describes what sql injection attacks are and how to prevent them.

Comment: I agree. But if EntityFramework would use parameterized queries it would not happen. 
That's why I wanted to know if there are any solutions to force EF to use this kind of queries at any times. Thank you for the sample code.

Comment: You can use lambda as `Regex.Replace(str, "...", match => { ... })`